# How to negate a regex expression?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I am checking a string assigned to the variable `s` and I have this so far:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[\d]+") Then something
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[A-Z]+") Then something
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[a-z]+") Then something
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[$%&*_=+^]+") Then something
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "^([\d]|[A-Z]|[a-z]|[$%&*-_=+^])") Then something
```

The problem lies with my last expression. I am trying to say, if you have anything other than a digit, uppercase, lowercase or one of my allowed symbols then do something. I have tried to use negation `^` but it isn't working.
Each if statement is setting a counter so this isn't an if, else if scenario

Comment: Try [`[^a-zA-Z0-9$%\&\*\-\_=\+\^]`](https://regex101.com/r/yBbLwN/2/)

Comment: what about using an if/else if/else construct?

Comment: Hmm, its giving me a parsing error: Unrecognized escape sequence \_.'

Comment: @chrisz Thanks for prompt reply

Comment: @Rich I don't know how `vb.net` handles escaping characters in regex, so you'll have to account for that

Comment: When you have `^` outside the brackets/parentheses, that is saying "look for this at the front of the string", that symbol needs to be in front of the characters you're escaping. I tried the `[^\d|^a-z|^A-Z\^$|^%|^&|^*|^\-|^_|^=|^+]` with the test string `abcDEF123$%&*-_=+#` at [.Net Regex Tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester) and it only highlighted the pound sign, which I think is what you want..?

Comment: @chrisz Yeah..but its still really helpful.

Comment: @soohoonigan That works! Clever! So is it not possible to negate the entire sequence with just the one carat?

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Thanks for the response. I don't think I could make this work because I'm actually counting one instance of each character. Its just that my question is too vague to have made this clear. Apologies

Comment: One option you do have is setting a boolean value to true in each of the If statements and then checking that it is false before doing the last "something"

Comment: @Rich : You can negate an entire Regex check by changing the `If`-statement either to: `If Not Regex.IsMatch(...) Then` or: `If Regex.IsMatch(...) = False Then`.

Comment: Perhaps, you've better explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a boolean to keep track of your progress through each check.

```
Dim matches = False
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[\d]+") Then matches = True
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[A-Z]+") Then matches = True
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[a-z]+") Then matches = True
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[$%&*_=+^]+") Then matches = True
If Not matches Then something
```

Then just change each statement to multiline syntax if you want to perform other operations within them rather than just checking if they match.

Comment: Using a `matches` variable is better than a redundant regex. +1

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to negate it, simply use `ElseIf` for all those cases and then use `Else` for the last one:

```
If Regex.IsMatch(s, "[\d]+") Then
    'something
ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(s, "[A-Z]+") Then
    'something
ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(s, "[a-z]+") Then
    'something
ElseIf Regex.IsMatch(s, "[$%&*_=+^]+") Then
    'something
Else
    'something
End If
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work. My apologies if the question is vague but its not an elseif scenario. I am not looking to find is there is a digit then do something but if there is an uppercase character then do something else. PS I did not downvote

Comment: If the question is vague, then you need to clarify it. I don't see why this will not work unless you are actually not doing what you said you're doing in the question. You already checked if your variable was one of those cases, so the `Else` will only execute if none of the cases has executed, which is identical to negating the regex, but with much better performance.

Comment: @RacilHilan  Im using one line if statements for a purpose. Will edit the question

Comment: I believe I understand now. OP is saying that more than one If statement can be entered for a single input, which would match their existing code. However it isn't clear.

Comment: @Racil : I didn't downvote either, but I think the OP wants to do something for _every_ condition that is true, rather than for just one of them. Though that doesn't explain why he couldn't just change his last statement to `If Not`. :)

Comment: @VisualVincent Yes I do want to do something for every condition that is true

Comment: @VisualVincent I actually was about to suggest `If Not`, but then I thought that was redundant and a simple `Else` will do the job better. Now with the new info, it seems `If Not` is the way to go, but Callum has already posted an answer with that.